# What is the best javascript framework that can create and manipulate SVG?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, html, svg

I would like to create visual modelling tools that integrate with Eclipse. I consider SVG to be a good way to represent the visual model, because it is vector based. And also in Eclipse I can use the internal browser as an engine to load svg+ecmascript+javascript+html. But there are so many JavaScript frameworks that utilize SVG, and now I got confused.

I am not so good in JavaScript, but i can use it in basic use. I think the framework must be easy to use, has a lot of examples/tutorials. It also has good documentation and a community where I can ask around.

Comment: Asking for the 'best' anything is a pretty clear indicator that the question is seeking subjective opinions and thus is not appropriate for Stack Overflow (though it may be a good question with otherwise helpful opinions and recommendations). It's even worse when you don't supply your fitness criteria for what 'best' means: fastest runtime? fastest developer time? smallest codebase? great documentation? most popular? least expensive? most permissive open-source license? strong community? fastest support times? most tutorials?

Comment: @Phrogz: I think I have said it explicitly the criteria I want --> " I think the framework must be easy to use, has a lot of examples/tutorials. It also has good documentations and community where I can ask around". Are those not the criteria? Forgive me if I am wrong, but I am pretty sure those are my criteria for the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Raphaël.js](http://raphaeljs.com) - a small JavaScript library that should simplify your work with vector graphics on the web.

Comment: Please check before posting to avoid duplicate comments as I have already mentioned this.

Comment: @Magrangs: yes, I did.  Sometimes other answers don't appear until you've posted yours, especially when they are posted within ~1min of each other.

Comment: thanks maeric, i will try this one :)

Answer (score 4):

I have used Raphael.js and find it quite good and easy to use.

http://raphaeljs.com/